# Should additional animations be shown *after* the first app-app transition?

Tags: ios, security, animation, apple, context-sensitive-help

On a new iOS device, when I try to open a special URL (app URL, universal link, or phone number), iOS will ask me if I want to "Open in X app"

[image]

When this occurs, a visual animation occurs that transitions from one app to another.

Sometimes, this visual transition is too much of a distraction, or irrelevant.

**Question**

- Are there any visual techniques to minimize the transition to/from the apps?
- Is there any visual technique I can use to "enhance" the transition, to show meaning in what's going on?

My case involves:

1. **AppA** opens **AppB** using a universal link.
2. **AppB** processes the URL parameters in the GET request of the link.
3. **AppB** then redirects back to **AppA**

Assume that step two take almost no time (100ms). The result to the end user is a lot of transfers back and forth.

Is there any way to reduce or enhance the visual animation to that it is more relevant to my SSO action?

Comment: You mentioned that sometimes this visual transition is too much of a distraction or irrelevant. I think both of these are good reasons for it to be removed rather than reduced. There are other ways to make users aware of where they are and what the focus is.

Answer (score 1):

I this you are talking about iOS animation and transistions.
If yes,iOS uses motion effects to create the perception of depth on your Home screen and within apps. If you have sensitivity to motion effects or screen movement on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, you can use Reduce Motion to turn off these effects.

To turn on Reduce Motion, go to Settings > General > Accessibility and tap the slider for Reduce Motion.

When Reduce Motion is on, certain screen effects change or are disabled on your device, including:
Screen transitions and effects use the dissolve effect instead of zoom or slide effects.
Parallax effect where your wallpaper, apps, and alerts that move or shift slightly as you tilt your device are disabled.
Animation and effects in certain apps are disabled. For example, weather animations in the Weather app.

[check in apple site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202655)